# Unique values in a C# List

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I was using MVC3 with Entity framework. This time I wanted to make unique items in list. Here is my list of items.

**List**

```
1.Overdue-1
2.Overdue-M
3.ItemsDue-1
4.ItemsDue-5
```

Among the above list, I just wanted to filter to get only this list,

```
1.Overdue
2.Itemsdue
```

Also, I need to make this one as DropdownList where Overdue or Itemsdue as Dropdown Text field & 1 to n as Value field. I have tried this one. But I could do the logic for Dropdown and Unique list.

**Code**

```
var select = (from asd in db.Sys
                      select new EmailTemp
                      {
                          SysCode = asd.Code,
                          SysmailId = asd.Id
                      }).Distinct().ToList();
        List<EmailTemp> filterlist = new List<EmailTemp>();
        foreach (var a in select)
        {
            string lates = a.SysCode;
            var ind = lates.IndexOf("-");
            if (ind > 0)
            {
                a.SysCode = lates.Substring(0, ind);
                a.SysmailId = a.SysmailId;
                filterlist.Add(a);
            }
            else
            {
                a.SysCode = lates;
                a.SysmailId = a.SysmailId;
                filterlist.Add(a);
            }
        }
        //var idlist = filterlist.Distinct().ToList();
        ViewBag.SysMailType = new SelectList(filterlist.Distinct().ToList(), "SysmailId", "SysCode");
```

Pls anyone tell me the possibilities that i can write down the code to achieve my logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) and use that to compare the items using `Distinct`.

```
class MyEqualityComparer: EqualityComparer<EmailTemp>
{
    private string GetPrefix(string s)
    {
        var pos = sIndexOf("-");
        var rslt = (pos > 0) ? s.SubString(0, pos) : s;
        return rslt;
    }

    public override bool Equals(EmailTemp t1, EmailTemp t2)
    {
        var s1 = GetPrefix(t1.SysCode);
        var s2 = GetPrefix(t2.SysCode);
        return s1.Equals(s2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(EmailTemp t1)
    {
        return GetPrefix(t1.SysCode).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And, to generate the list of unique items:

```
List<EmailTemp> filterList = select.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

There's probably a way to combine that with your first LINQ expression. Perhaps somebody else will chime in.